# Weight-loss calculator

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, calculator

I have a table that holds a user's weight for specific days. In my `weights_controller.rb` index action I can show these weights - no problem. What I also want to show on the index is the user's current weight, his weight loss over time as well as the timeframe he achieved this weight loss.

Thus I created a **weight_calculator.rb** to do the needed calculations:

```
class WeightCalculator
  def initialize(profile, user)
     @profile = profile
     @user = user
  end

  def current_weight
    @current_weight = Weight.where(:user_id => @user.id).order(:day).last
  end

  def weight_loss
    @current_weight = Weight.where(:user_id => @user.id).order(:day).last
    @start_weight = Weight.where(:user_id => @user.id).order(:day).first
    @weight_loss = @current_weight.kilograms - @start_weight.kilograms
  end

  def timeframe
    @current_weight = Weight.where(:user_id => @user.id).order(:day).last
    @start_weight = Weight.where(:user_id => @user.id).order(:day).first
    @weight_loss_timeframe = @current_weight.day - @start_weight.day
    @weeks = @weight_loss_timeframe.to_i/7
  end
end
```

This is my **weights_controller.rb** index action:

```
  def index
    @weights = Weight.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order(day: :desc)
    @weight_loss = WeightCalculator.new(@profile, current_user).weight_loss
    @weeks = WeightCalculator.new(@profile, current_user).timeframe

    @result = {}
    Weight.where(:user_id => current_user.id).each do |weight|
      @result[weight.day] = weight.kilograms
    end

    @profile = Profile.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end
```

Everything works fine in this setup. However, there is clearly some repition in my `weight_calculator.rb` and I am asking myself what would be the best way to write this code to be DRY conform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is really quite a lot wrong here.

As a *very* simple improvement, why aren't you using ActiveRecord's associations? Why do you constantly do this...

```
Weight.where(:user_id => current_user.id).each ...
# ...
@current_weight = Weight.where(:user_id => @user.id).order(:day).last
```

Instead of this?

```
current_user.weights.each ...
# ... 
current_weight = @user.weights.order(:day).last
```

That alone would drastically improve the readability of your code.

You can also make the loop in your `index` action more idiomatic:

```
@result = current_user.weights.map do
  [weight.day, weight.kilograms]
end.to_h
```

You also do some weird things in `WeightCalculator` with instance vairables. Your methods all seem to *both* return a value, and assign that same value to an instance vairable that is never used. There is no reason to do this:

```
def current_weight
  # ...
  @current_weight = <calculation>
end
```

Instead, you should just return the calculation, or *memoize* it via `||=`:

```
def current_weight
  # ...
  @current_weight ||= <calculation>
end
```

If I were working on this code, I would refactor it in the following way to take advantage of the above few points:

```
class WeightCalculator
  def initialize(profile, user)
     @profile = profile
     @user = user
  end

  def weights
    Weight.where(:user_id => @user.id)
    # or this, doesn't matter:
    @weights ||= @user.weights
  end

  def start_weight
    @start_weight ||= weights.order(:day).first
  end

  def current_weight
    @current_weight ||= weights.order(:day).last
  end

  def weight_loss
    current_weight.kilograms - start_weight.kilograms
  end

  def timeframe
    (current_weight.day - start_weight.day).to_i / 7
  end
end
```

---

Your index action is also pretty broken.

First, You try to access `@profile` to pass it to your `WeightCalculator` before you set it, and then later you set it to `Profile.where(...)`, which returns an association, not a specific profile. Again, using associations, you probably just want

```
@profile = current_user.profile
```

Second, you query Weights all over the place, over and over. You constantly go through the effort of typing out `Weight.where(...)` instead of just **doing it once** and reusing the returned set of weights.  You even make multiple calculators for absolutely no reason, and inside the calculator you don't even reuse `weights`! Just do things once, there is no reason to continually run the same queries over and over, even if they are being cached by ActiveRecord.

```
calculator = WeightCalculator.new(@profile, current_user)
@weights = calculator.weights

@result = @weights.map do |weight|
  [weight.day, weight.kilograms]
end.to_h
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for this massive input. I will work through it. However, using @weights ||= current_user.weights results in an "undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<WeightCalculator:0x007f834890d170>" error.

Using @weights ||= @user.weights works. (Sorry btw. for my crappy code. Just started coding two months ago :-/)